# $ P\mid n \implies \exists (a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}^2 \quad an+b(p-1)=1$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

> show that 
>   $$ p\mid n \implies \exists (a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}^2 \quad  an+b(p-1)=1$$ with p is the least prime dividing

my attempts

Indeed,
Let $d=n\wedge (p-1)=gcd(n,p-1)$ and we try to show that $d=1$

since $d=n\wedge (p-1)$ then $d/n \implies  d \leq  p-1$

if $d\neq 1$ then d has prime divisor $q$ such that $q\mid (d\mid n)$

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Am i not seeing something there? $n=6,p=3$

Answer (score 3):

Presumably $\,p\,$ is the *least* prime dividing $\,n,\,$ hence $\,\gcd(n,p-1)=1\,$ so [Bezout's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) for said gcd yields the desired equation.

Notice $\,n\,$ and $\,p\!-\!1\,$ are coprime because they have disjoint sets of prime factors: by hypothesis $\,n\,$ has all prime factors $\,\ge p\,$ but $\,p\!-\!1\,$ has all prime factors $\le p\!-\!1$

Comment: just question we can say if p is the least prime dividing  then gcd(n,p-1)=1 without proof

Comment: @Educ If prime $\,q\mid\color{#c00} n,\color{#0a0}{p\!-\!1}\,$ then $\,q\le\color{#0a0}{ p\!-\!1}\,$ contra $\,q\ge p\,$ by $\,p\,$ is the least prime factor of $\,\color{#c00}n.\ \ $

Comment: yes could you finish my proof  please

Comment: @Educ You have the right idea but your notation is wrong. You want $\ d\mid n,p\!-\!1\,$ not $\ d = n \wedge p\!-\!1.\ \ $

Comment: no \wedge =gcd when its equal =1

Comment: @Educ I added a remark which explains the intuition behind the coprimality.

Comment: please could you follow my idea to show that gcd(p-1,n)=1

Comment: @Educ The proof in your edit is fine, but you should say more explictly how you obtain a contradiction if $\, d > 1.\ $

Comment: i don't have any idea about that if you could help me to write that case

Comment: @Educ It is as I said in the answer: if prime $\,q\,$ divides both $\,n\,$ and $\,p\!-\!1\,$ then $\,q\ge p\,$ (by leastness of $p),\,$ and $\,q\le p-1\,$ (by $\,q\mid p\!-\!1),\,$ contradiction.

Comment: this is case for $d\neq 1$

Comment: could you write proof more explicity than me contains both case $d\geq 1$ and $d\neq 1$

Comment: @Educ If $\,d>1\,$ then is has a prime factor $\,q,\,$ etc. I recommend that you try to understand the proof that I wrote in terms of disjointness of sets of prime factors, which makes the intuition clearer. Do you understand the 2nd paragraph of my answer?